# How to customize bash autocomplete to list the files in another directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

How to customize bash autocomplete to list the files in another directory 
for only one script option (-seq), for other script options (-speed, -define) default autocomplete is O.K. 
this is what I have

```
 export files=`ls /home/tests/`
 echo $files #debug     

 _xtest ()   {              
      local cur
      COMPREPLY=()     
      cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
       #case "$cur" in
       COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) )
    #  esac
      return 0
    }

    complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```

How to enable default bash completion for other options ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should use prev instead of cur :

```
_xtest ()   {              
      local prev
      COMPREPLY=()     
      prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
      case "$prev" in
       -seq )
          COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) ) ;;
      esac
      return 0
    }
complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```